# How to add an if statement to my WooCommerce search form

Tags: php, html, wordpress

Using the inbuilt WordPress search form:

```
<form role="search" method="get" class="search-form">

<?php
  if ( function_exists( 'woocommerce_product_search' ) ) {
    echo woocommerce_product_search( array( 'limit' => 40 ) );
  }
?>

<div class="col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-4">
  <div class="input-group">
    <input type='textbox' maxlength="8" id="item-search" name="s" class="form-control form-inline" value="<?php the_search_query();?>" placeholder="Enter your postcode e.g. SW1Y 4LG"/>
    <span class="input-group-btn">
      <button class="item-search-btn">search</button>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>

</form>
```

I have called it to appear on my home page (index.php):

```
<?php get_search_form(); ?>
```

I want to add an if statement to display:

```
<div id="postcode-no" class="col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-4">
    Unfortunately this is incorrect.
</div>
```

So to my index.php file I have added:

```
<?php if (input-text=='SW12') { ?>
    <div id="postcode-no" class="col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-4">
        Unfortunately this is incorrect.
    </div>
<?php } else if (input-text=='SW15'){ ?>
    <div id="postcode-no2" class="col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-4">
        Correct.
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

But it's not working. I'm fairly new to PHP. What have I done wrong?

Comment: you can use $input-text as var not input-text and print first $input-text so you will know what will be output. and use else statement for better understandably

Comment: Oh ok, I see what you mean. Thank you. Do you have an answer to the code? @mollie

Comment: Please check below code

Comment: Absolutely brilliant! Thank you @mollie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Chaneg the var input-text to $input_text than try 
<?php if ($input_text=='SW12'): ?>
<div id="postcode-no" class="col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-4">
    Unfortunately this is incorrect.
</div>
<?php elseif ($input_text=='SW15'): ?>
<div id="postcode-no2" class="col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-4">
    Correct.
</div>
<?php else: ?>
<div id="postcode-no2" class="col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-4">
    Some Else.
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```